# how to display hctreemap2 unique levels?

Tags: r, highcharts, treemap

i'm trying to create a treemap plot using highchart, i want to create with levels, i mean, in the first view te user should see only "Continent", in second level "Country", but now the output give me so much times the same Continent, how can i modify the code to display only one time the continents and when the user click on any, display countries?. This is my code now.

```
hctreemap2(data = GNI2014,
           group_vars = c("continent", "iso3"),
           size_var = "population",
           color_var = "GNI",
           layoutAlgorithm = "squarified",
           levelIsConstant = FALSE,
           levels = list(
             list(level = 1, dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)),
             list(level = 2, dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)),
             list(level = 3, dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE))
           )) %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(minColor = brewer.pal(7, "Greens")[1],
               maxColor = brewer.pal(7, "Greens")[7]) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "<b>{point.name}</b>:<br>
                            Pop: {point.value:,.0f}<br>
                            GNI: {point.colorValue:,.0f}")
```

Tkanks

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a problem with interpreting this data at the first level - the name property should be the name of the country, not the continent. Here you can see a simplified demo with sample data (continent and countries) - which can show you how this can be done:

```
highchart() %>% 
 hc_add_series(
   type = "treemap",
   layoutAlgorithm = "squarified",
   allowDrillToNode = TRUE,
   levels = list(
     list(
       level = 1,
       dataLabels = list(
         enabled = TRUE
       ),
       borderWidth = 3
     ),
     list(
       level = 2,
       dataLabels = list(
         enabled = TRUE
       ),
       borderWidth = 2
     )
   ),
   data = list(
     # LEVEL I
     list(
       id = "Asia",
       name = "Asia",
       color = "#EC2500"
     ),
     list(
       id = "Europe",
       name = "Europe",
       color = "#ECE100"
     ),
     # LEVEL II
     list(
       name = "Russia",
       parent = "Asia",
       value = 4
     ),
     list(
       name = "China",
       parent = "Asia",
       value = 2
     ),
     list(
       id = "Poland",
       name = "Poland",
       parent = "Europe"
     ),
     list(
       id = "UK",
       name = "UK",
       parent = "Europe"
     ),
     # LEVEL 3
     list(
       name = "Warsaw",
       parent = "Poland",
       value = 3
     ),
     list(
       name = "Krakow",
       parent = "Poland",
       value = 3
     ),
     list(
       id = "SP",
       name = "London",
       value = 5,
       parent = "UK"
     )
   )
 )
```